# sed: search 5 lines text anche change only first and last

Tags: text, sed

I need to find in a long list of files 5 lines like:

```
TEXT 1
Text 2
Text 3
Text 4
Text 5
```

and change it with

```
NEW TEXT 1
Text 2
Text 3
Text 4
NEW TEXT 5
```

I need to that the command will match any text for the 3 lines "Text 2/3/4" and keep them in the result.

Example 2:
Initial text:

```
TEXT 1
Pippo
Pluto
Paperino
Text 5
```

Result:

```
NEW TEXT 1 XXXX
Pippo
Pluto
Paperino
NEW Text 5 XXXX
```

The matching strings are not the first and last line of text.

I tried this command, but I don't know how to copy 
the text in substitution text:

```
sed 'N;N;N;N;N;TEXT 1.*Text 5/NEW TEXT 1.*Text 5' filename
```

Thanks

Comment: `sed -r 'N;N;N;N;N;TEXT 1(.*)Text 5/NEW TEXT 1\1Text 5' filename`: use parenthesis and backreference `\1`.

Comment: Didn't you miss the `s` command?
`sed -r 'N;N;N;N;N;s/TEXT 1(.*)Text 5/NEW TEXT 1\1Text 5/' filename`